# android billing how to enable enablePendingPurchases()

Tags: android, billing

I've moved from an old gradle of billing api, to the most recent to date, and now I've tried adding

```
  BillingClient.Builder enablePendingPurchases = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this);
```

but I can not get it to work, here's the error

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Support for pending purchases must be enabled. Enable this by calling 'enablePendingPurchases()' on BillingClientBuilder.
        at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient$Builder.build(BillingClient.java:309)
        at com.aplicacion.vivaluganoapp.ar.ponerDineroActivity.setupBillingClient(ponerDineroActivity.java:144)
        at com.aplicacion.vivaluganoapp.ar.ponerDineroActivity.onCreate(ponerDineroActivity.java:125)
```

complete code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poner_dinero);

        recyclerProduct.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerProduct.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        BillingClient.Builder enablePendingPurchases = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this);

 enablePendingPurchases.build();
setupBillingClient();
    }




    private void setupBillingClient() {


        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder (this).setListener(this).build();

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult responseCode) {
                int maca = BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK;
                String maca2 = String.valueOf(maca);

                String maca3 = String.valueOf(responseCode);
                if (maca3 == maca2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ponerDineroActivity.this, "WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ponerDineroActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Toast.makeText(ponerDineroActivity.this, "Disconnected from Billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

if I place only:

```
BillingClient.Builder enablePendingPurchases = BillingClient.newBuilder(this);
```

the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please provide a valid listener for purchases updates.
```

any  help?  i'm  tired of trying

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the first stacktrace in your question

> Enable this by calling 'enablePendingPurchases()'

we can find documentation for method `enablePendingPurchases()`

> This method is required to be called to acknowledge your application
>   has been updated to support purchases that are pending. Pending
>   purchases are not automatically enabled since your application will
>   require updates to ensure entitlement is not granted before payment
>   has been secured. For more information on how to handle pending
>   transactions see
>   https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview
>
> If this method is not called, BillingClient instance creation fails.

**Your line of code should be:-**

```
enablePendingPurchases = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
   .enablePendingPurchases()
   .setListener(this);
```

**Instead of :-**

```
enablePendingPurchases = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this);
```

Comment: what worked for me was to place:

  billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder (this) .setListener (this) .enablePendingPurchases (). build ();

but thanks to your answer I can achieve it

Comment: `enablePendingPurchases` and `setListener` are required!

Comment: When you enable pending purchases, you also need to check the Purchase object for the PURCHASED or PENDING purchase state, using getPurchaseState(). "Note that you should grant entitlement only when the state is PURCHASED." https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#pending

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

Just add `enablePendingPurchases()` like below:

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                             .setListener(this)
                             .enablePendingPurchases()
                             .build();
```

Comment: When you enable pending purchases, you also need to check the Purchase object for the PURCHASED or PENDING purchase state, using getPurchaseState(). "Note that you should grant entitlement only when the state is PURCHASED." https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#pending

Comment: @ChrisCartland I am migrating AIDL to Billing v4. I have PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT"); Shall I use the above for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
BillingClient billingClient = 
BillingClient.newBuilder(context!!)
.enablePendingPurchases()
.setListener(this)
 build()
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                skuList =  HashMap()
                skuList.put(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, listOf(getString(R.string.subscription_monthly),getString(R.string.subscription_yearly)))

                querySkuDetailsAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,skuList.get(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS),object :SkuDetailsResponseListener{
                    override fun onSkuDetailsResponse(billingResult: BillingResult?, skuDetailsList: MutableList<SkuDetails>?) {

                        DebugLog.e("DATAAA "+skuDetailsList?.size+"")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    })
```